# Is it possible to put application shortcuts in a folder on desktop and launch them from that folder?

Tags: unity, shortcuts

I'm sorry if this question has been asked countless times.  i've been googling this question for about two hours to no avail.  I have only limited experience with ubuntu from back in the 16.04 days, and back then i could just create a folder on desktop and drag my application shortcuts into that folder and still launch them.

I do not know if I did anything special back then to make it work, but is it possible to do this still in 20.04?  I've tried to just put them into a folder on the desktop, and the .desktop files just open in the text editor.

I appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 0):

As such, indeed, this is **not anymore supported**, probably in the context of security. Also running script by double clicking them in the file manager is not anymore directly supported.

To run a .desktop file, place it in the folder `.local/share/applications`. Any (valid) `.desktop` file that resides there will appear in your application overview (or menu on other desktops). You can run it from there and optionally pin it to the Ubuntu Dock for quick access.

Ubuntu also supports running them directly from your desktop. Put them on the desktop. Do that by moving them in the file manager to your Desktop folder under your home folder. Direct drag and drop from the file manager to the desktop does not work currently. Right-click the .desktop file and select "Allow lauching" to turn the `.desktop` file into a regular application icon that you can launch.

Comment: Thank you.  While this saddens me in regards to my usual organization methods, i shall adapt to using the dock and dashboard.  Alternatively, is there any desktop grouping application like fedora plasma has but for ubuntu?

Comment: Feel free to accept a new question as a new question (not in the comments) on this site, and consider accepting this answer if it helped you, even if it unfortunately is not the answer that you hoped for.